# Unable to fetch entity from nsset by attribute on subsequent attempts

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity, fetch

2 entities:  **User** and **Buildings**.

**User** has an attribute with type **NSSet** named **buildings**

I want to retrieve the **Buildings** entity from **NSSet** by attribute **guid**.

On the first run of the application, adding data succeeds.  Data can be retrieved and displayed correctly.  After the application is closed and then subsequent attempts to get existent buildings entities by guid fail.   The first time `getBuildingsByGuid` returns `nil` because there are no entities; when I call the function **getBuildingsByGuid** and there are entities in buildings set, the application crashes.  Fetching with predicate works; the relations between entities are: one user to many buildings.

Unable to catch the instruction via debugging.

In the **User** object, the following custom method should get **Buildings**:

```
- (Buildings *)getBuildingsByGuid:(NSString *)guid
{
    for (Buildings *buildings in self.buildings)
    {
        if ([buildings.guid isEqualToString:guid])
            return buildings;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Edit:
My entity User header contains:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Buildings, TableBuildings;

@interface User : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * first_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * guid_contact;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * guid_user;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * guid_userRole;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * last_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * role_code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * role_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * token;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type_code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *buildings;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *tableBuildings;

@end

@interface User (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

// Buildings
- (void)addBuildingsObject:(Buildings *)value;
- (void)removeBuildingsObject:(Buildings *)value;
- (void)addBuildings:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeBuildings:(NSSet *)values;
- (BOOL)containsBuildingsObject:(Buildings*)value;
- (Buildings *)getBuildingsByGuid:(NSString *)guid;

// TableBuildings
- (void)addTableBuildingsObject:(TableBuildings *)value;
- (void)removeTableBuildingsObject:(TableBuildings *)value;
- (void)addTableBuildings:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeTableBuildings:(NSSet *)values;
- (BOOL)containsTableBuildingsObject:(TableBuildings*)value;
- (TableBuildings *)getTableBuildingsByGuid:(NSString *)guid;

@end
```

The implementation file:

```
#import "User.h"
#import "Buildings.h"
#import "TableBuildings.h"


@implementation User

@dynamic email;
@dynamic first_name;
@dynamic guid_contact;
@dynamic guid_user;
@dynamic guid_userRole;
@dynamic last_name;
@dynamic password;
@dynamic role_code;
@dynamic role_name;
@dynamic token;
@dynamic type_code;
@dynamic type_name;
@dynamic buildings;
@dynamic tableBuildings;

@end

@implementation User (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

#pragma mark - Buildings management methods

- (void)addBuildingsObject:(Buildings *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"buildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"buildings"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"buildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)removeBuildingsObject:(Buildings *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"buildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"buildings"] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"buildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)addBuildings:(NSSet *)values
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"buildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:values];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"buildings"] unionSet:values];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"buildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:values];
}

- (void)removeBuildings:(NSSet *)values
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"buildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:values];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"buildings"] unionSet:values];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"buildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:values];
}

- (BOOL) containsBuildingsObject:(Buildings*)value
{
    for (Buildings *buildings in self.buildings)
    {
        if( [buildings.guid isEqualToString:value.guid])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (Buildings *)getBuildingsByGuid:(NSString *)guid
{
    for (Buildings *buildings in self.buildings)
    {
        if ([buildings.guid isEqualToString:guid])
            return buildings;
    }
    return nil;
}

#pragma mark - TableBuildings management methods

- (void)addTableBuildingsObject:(TableBuildings *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"tableBuildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"tableBuildings"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"tableBuildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)removeTableBuildingsObject:(TableBuildings *)value
{
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"tableBuildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"tableBuildings"] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"tableBuildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)addTableBuildings:(NSSet *)values
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"tableBuildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:values];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"tableBuildings"] unionSet:values];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"tableBuildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:values];
}

- (void)removeTableBuildings:(NSSet *)values
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"tableBuildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:values];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"tableBuildings"] unionSet:values];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"tableBuildings" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:values];
}

-(BOOL) containsTableBuildingsObject:(TableBuildings*)value
{
    for (TableBuildings *tableBuildings in self.tableBuildings)
    {
        if( [tableBuildings.guid_building isEqualToString:value.guid_building])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (TableBuildings *)getTableBuildingsByGuid:(NSString *)guid
{
    for (TableBuildings *tableBuildings in self.tableBuildings)
    {
        if ([tableBuildings.guid_building isEqualToString:guid])
            return tableBuildings;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

@end

When the app start will fetch User by email and password:

```
user = [[DataController instance] fetchEntityOfType:object_User withPredicate:@"email = %@ AND password = %@", username, passwordMD5];
```

Later, when I want to display my buildings list I call the method getBuildingsByGuid like this:

```
// buildings is parsed from json and have NSDictionary type
for (NSDictionary *building in buildings)
    {
        NSString *guid_building = [building safeObjectForKey:@"guid"];

        // get building and check if is associated to the current user
        BuildingPerUser *buildingPerUser = [[DataController instance] fetchEntityOfType:object_BuildingPerUser withPredicate:@"guid_user = %@ AND guid_building = %@", guid_user, guid_building];

        //create new association if not exists
        if (!buildingPerUser)
        {
            buildingPerUser = [[[DataController instance] newEnityOfType:object_BuildingPerUser] autorelease];
            buildingPerUser.guid_user = guid_user;
            buildingPerUser.guid_building = guid_building;
        }

        Buildings *buildingRow = [user getBuildingsByGuid:guid_building];

        // create new building if not exists
        if (!buildingRow)
        {
            buildingRow = [[[DataController instance] newEnityOfType:object_Buildings] autorelease];
            buildingRow.guid = guid_building;
            [user addBuildingsObject:buildingRow];
        }

        // update building
        buildingRow.name = [building safeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        buildingRow.isNew = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

        [delComplementBuildings addObject:guid_building];
    }
```

If I use:

```
Buildings *buildingRow = [[DataController instance] fetchEntityOfType:object_Buildings withPredicate:@"guid = %@", guid_building];
```

... my app work. With:

```
Buildings *buildingRow = [user getBuildingsByGuid:guid_building];
```

.. the app crash.

I preffer to use objects instead of predicate fetching...

Another edit: I found the exception: *relationship fault* about nsset entity of **Buildings**
Below is the listing of Buildings:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class TableBuildings, User;

@interface Buildings : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * guid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isNew;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *tableBuildings;
@property (nonatomic, retain) User *user;
@end

@interface Buildings (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addTableBuildingsObject:(TableBuildings *)value;
- (void)removeTableBuildingsObject:(TableBuildings *)value;
- (void)addTableBuildings:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeTableBuildings:(NSSet *)values;
@end

#import "Buildings.h"
#import "TableBuildings.h"
#import "User.h"


@implementation Buildings

@dynamic guid;
@dynamic isNew;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic tableBuildings;
@dynamic user;

@end
```

The buildings accessors are not implemented yet.

**Problem resolved. It was a mistake on initializing User. The solution: use property for User.**

Comment: What kind of crash is it?  What's the message in the debugger?

Comment: Give random error with unrecognized selector instance about different types of objects, or in other cases does not give anything. I tried to debug, everything seems ok until use the method. then the application stops and manifests as above. The log instances disappear. Tomorrow I'll post more about how I treat the code